# What should be $W$ in $I_W$ when choosing randomly uniformly a point $(x,y)$ inside triangle?

Tags: probability

We choose randomly uniformly a point $(x,y)$ inside triangle that it's points are $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$ and $(1,0)$. So we can say that:
$$
f_{X,Y}(x,y)=\frac{1}{S_B}=\frac{1}{0.5}I_{\{0<y<1,y<1-x,0<x<1\}}=2I_{\{0<y<1,y<1-x,0<x<1\}}=2I_{\{0<x<1,0<y<x-1\}}
$$
where $S_B$ is the area of the triangle.

I'm trying to build myself a formula of the indictor $I$ for any three points $(a_1,b_1)$, $(a_2,b_2)$ and  $(a_3,b_3)$. What should be $W$ in $I_W$ if we replace the three points above general $(a_1,b_1)$, $(a_2,b_2)$ and  $(a_3,b_3)$ points?

Answer (score 0):

By contracting and sliding one edge of a triangle towards its opposing vertex, we can see that this covers the triangle interior completely, and that every point in a triangle can be uniquely referenced by two of its sides as all the triangles are similar.

Define a parameter for each edge, say $\alpha, \beta$, and then:

$$W=\{w=(x,y)+\alpha v_1+\beta v_2 : 0\le \alpha,\beta\le 1\}$$

where $v_1,v_2$ are the vector edges, and $(x,y)$ is their point of intersection.

Answer (score 0):

In [barycentric coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barycentric_coordinate_system)
a point internal to the triangle (or any other convex polygon) with vertices ${\bf v}_k$
is given by the weighted average of the verices with positive cooefficients
$$
\eqalign{
  & {\bf p} = \left( {\matrix{   x  \cr   y  \cr  } } \right)
 = {{a{\bf v}_1  + b{\bf v}_2  + c{\bf v}_3 } \over {a + b + c}}\quad \left| {\;0 \le a,b,c} \right. =   \cr 
  &  = \alpha {\bf v}_1  + \beta {\bf v}_2  + \left( {1 - \alpha  - \beta } \right){\bf v}_3  =   \cr 
  &  = \alpha \left( {{\bf v}_1  - {\bf v}_3 } \right) + \beta \left( {{\bf v}_2  - {\bf v}_3 } \right) + {\bf v}_3
  = \quad \left| \matrix{
  \;0 \le \alpha ,\beta \left( { \le 1} \right) \hfill \cr 
  \;\left( {0 \le } \right)\alpha  + \beta  \le 1 \hfill \cr}  \right. \cr} 
$$
So $\alpha , \beta$ are the coordinates inside a right triangle with unit sides.

Since
$$
\left( {\matrix{
   {dx}  \cr 
   {dy}  \cr 
 } } \right) = \left( {\matrix{
   {x_1  - x_3 } & {x_2  - x_3 }  \cr 
   {y_1  - y_3 } & {y_2  - y_3 }  \cr 
 } } \right)\left( {\matrix{
   {d\alpha }  \cr 
   {d\beta }  \cr 
 } } \right)
$$
then the Jacobian is constant and non null if the vertices are not aligned.

Therefore a uniform distribution of $(\alpha , \beta)$ will translate in a uniform
distribution of $(x,y)$.